# Send string that contains "https://url.org" via Ajax to PHP, Error 503 "Service not available"

Tags: php, ajax

I have a web application where I send a string via Ajax to a PHP script, which saves the string in a mySQL database. Works all great. Since a week, or so, I have a weird problem: The string is all saved fine, except when it contains "https://url.org" or any other "syntactically" correct URL. A string containing "https//url.org" just works fine.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var documentText = "Simple https://doi.org string to test the save function.";
   // Ajax call
   $.ajax({
      url: "../php/myphpfile.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
         documentText: documentText
      },
      success: function (response) {
         // Do something with the result
         console.log(response);
      },
      error: function (response) {
         // Do something with the result
         console.log(response);
      },
      complete: function (response) {
         // Do something with the result
         alert("Complete");
      }
   });
```

That is what the receiving myphpfile.php PHP file looks like

```
if( isset($_POST['documentText']) )
    {
        $documentText = $_POST['documentText'];
        $documentText = urlencode($documentText);
    }
// Now it inserts the string in mySQL database
include_once( '../config/someconfigstuff.php' );
$sql = "UPDATE table SET documentText='" . $documentText . "' WHERE documentId='1234'";
$result = mysqli_query( $mysqlConnection, $sql );    
mysqli_close( $mysqlConnection );
```

Only (!) if the string contains something like a valid URL, I get the error message from myphpfile.php. Otherwise, the string is all fine in the database. The field for documentText is of type LONG.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> 
<html><head>
<title>503 Service Unavailable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.</p>
</body></html>
```

I tried doing the URL-encoding in JavaScript before sending it via Ajax; result is the same.

I would very much appreciate an advice here.

This solved the problem:

```
$documentId='1234';
$documentText='Here is my text with https://url.org.';
include_once( '../config/someconfigstuff.php' );
$sql = "UPDATE table SET documentText=? WHERE documentId=?";
$stmt = $mysqlConnection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $documentText, $documentId);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: **Warning!** You're open to [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)! Read [how to prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) by using prepared statements with bound parameters instead of injecting variables directly into your queries. It's not just about security. If your data contains, for example, a single quote `'`, your query will break.

Comment: Why are you urlencoding the string in PHP before saving it in the database? If you use prepared statements as suggested above, you can simply save the string "as-is" and then only encode it when you use the value (since different use cases can require different encodings)

Comment: "Since a week" sounds like it worked before? What did you change in the meantime?

Comment: Check your PHP error log for a specific error message, which might help. But yes the way you're building your query is wrong, wrong wrong - and could easily also be related to your problem. Please read [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) and urgently apply that learning to your code, to avoid SQL injection risks, and also the risk of silly syntax errors breaking your SQL queries due to the characters contained in the input variables.

Comment: Thanks for the warning regarding the SQL injection. I am aware of it and have posted a simplified version (which gives me the error, too). @Nico Haase: I am not aware that I had changed anything. The website is on a hosted server and I am not changing anything there.

Comment: Thanks, I will check what you suggested.

Comment: Thanks. Applying the proper inclusion of PHP variables inside MySQL statements solved the problem:
$sql = "UPDATE table SET documentText=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $documentText, $id);
$stmt->execute();